# When this interaction is running , others interactions dosen't being received

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, sus

so, this is the code of the suspicious interaction code:
https://srcb.in/s6MOIk9S89
so when the suspicious code running, the bot can't received any other interaction failed:
https://i.ibb.co/2d8By3v/Screenshot-20220417-145902.jpg
and after i restart it, (stopping the suspicious interaction code) the bot can receive interactions again:
https://i.ibb.co/9nX1HkR/Screenshot-20220418-233220.jpg

this is the code to test it(img):

```js
let joined = []
client.on("interactionCreate",async(interaction)=> {
  await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral:true})
  if (interaction.customId === "join") {
    try {
    console.log(interaction)   
 if (joined.includes(interaction.user.id)) return interaction.editReply("You had already joined the game")
   if (joined.length === 40) return interaction.editReply("Sorry , the room is full")
   joined.push(interaction.user.id)
    interaction.editReply("Successfully joined the game")
  } catch(err) {
console.log(err)
    }
  }
```